# Можно ли взять современный процессор и сделать свой компьютер на его основе?

Tags: железо, процессор, эвм

Начал изучение архитектуры ЭВМ. В книге, которую я читаю, приводятся примеры с использованием микропроцессора Intel 8080. Могу ли я, например, взять какой-нибудь современный процессор (пусть будет, Ryzen 5), найти даташит и сделать компьютер на его основе так же, как и с Intel 8080?

Comment: Собрать из готовых компонент, продающихся в интернете (мать, память, корпус и т.д.)? Без сомнения, да.

Comment: @avp подозреваю, подразумевается самостоятельная сборка чего-то похожего на мать

Comment: @andreymal, думаю, в домашних условиях изготовить подходящую для современного проца плату не удастся

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Теоретически — да, это возможно. Ведь существует несколько производителей материнских плат.

Практически — скорее нет, и вот по каким причинам:

1. Сильно сомневаюсь, что удастся найти достаточно полную документацию. Если удастся, то за огромные деньги и, скорее всего, по соглашению о неразглашении (NDA).
2. Обвязка современных процессоров настолько сложна, что ее может спроектировать и изготовить только производитель процессора. Сейчас она делается в виде огромной микросхемы (chipset), а у 8080 это был набор стандартизованных отдельных микросхем (chip set — дословно «набор микросхем»).
3. Расстояние между выводами настолько маленькое, а количество их настолько велико, что современные материнские платы содержат токопроводящие дорожки не только на обеих поверхностях, но и до 15 слоев внутри платы. Изготовление таких плат возможно только роботами, а настройка линии делается только для больших партий. Единичное изделие будет стоить как самолет.
4. На частотах современных процессоров в проводниках паразитные эффекты (емкость, индуктивность, сопротивление и тому подобные) сравнимы с проектными. В мире не так много людей, способных проектировать платы работающие на таких частотах.

Современные процессоры для ПК давно перестали быть универсальными. Они специализированы для установки в ПК.

**PS**

На рынке всё еще есть другие производители, которые выпускают универсальные процессоры/микроконтроллеры/SoC, которые можно использовать в хоббийных проектах.

Например 8-битные Atmega (например, Atmega32) и 32-битные STM32, (например, STM32F103) вполне возможно запаять вручную, и изготовить под них плату в домашних условиях.

Тот же Intel выпускает SoC семейства Quark, которые продаются на платах с удобной разводкой, в том числе и Arduino-совместимых.

Comment: Кстати да, процессоры типа i486/i586 (как Quark, только в корпусе, который можно самому распаять), можно запустить. Под всякие даже Атомы (типа очень популярного Baytrail) можно и 4-6х слойной платой обойтись. Что до софта, то под тот же Baytrail есть U-Boot bare metal, то есть можно его в качестве начальной «ОС» использовать. Или смотреть в сторону Zephyr RTOS.